# achieve Sington with cyclic imports in python

Tags: python

I'm new in python.
I have two py files like this:
A.py

```
class LLL(object):
    pass

ak=LLL()
print(ak)

def f1():
    from B import tt

    print("hello")

if __name__=="__main__":
    f1()
```

and B.py

```
from A import ak
def tt():
    print("sss")

print(tt)
```

when i run A.py,i get the console below:

```
<__main__.LLL object at 0x0000000000B69BE0>
<A.LLL object at 0x0000000001461668>
<function tt at 0x000000000124AD90>
hello
```

My question is why ak create twice?In B.py,i want to get the ak created in A.py,not create a new ak,it looks like import B will run all A's code,how can i fix it?

Comment: The problem isn't that the imports are cyclic, it's that you're importing the same file you're running, which results it in being run twice (once as a script, and once as an import).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)